# Firefox: How to force address bar to expand/wrap over several lines so can see whole URL?

Tags: firefox, gui, address-bar

The URL in question has a long user ID string so the interesting part of the URL appears at the end which is always off-screen.

Anyone know how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
#urlbar *,
#FindToolbar *,
#search-container * { font-size:11pt !important; }

#urlbar .textbox-input-box,
#search-container .textbox-input-box, 
#FindToolbar .textbox-input-box
 { font-size:12pt !important; font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono"; }
```

to the [userChrome.css](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkb.mozillazine.org%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUserChrome.css%26printable%3Dyes&ei=kKUWUOyMJYjC0QXlyIGgCA&usg=AFQjCNHwHGkZ7boXUXWpoPA_8AT1DRh3oQ&sig2=MeRwrih6M6FlOrELwUtekg) file which is located in the chrome folder in your [Profile folder](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkb.mozillazine.org%2FProfile_folder_-_Firefox&ei=z6UWUKKvCaah0QXT6YGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGGHIXshzgJ3tsXnJYAbzk4G6BjAA&sig2=4kEjDgd3lL7I9xUFR5PgJg) (for more information on how to get there go to [Editing configuration](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration)).

If there is no chrome folder in your Profile folder, create a folder named `chrome` and create a plain text file inside the folder named `userChrome.css`.

---

You can also stretch the address bar by customizing the toolbar: re-sizing the Search Bar, thus making the address bar longer, and removing unneeded buttons or bookmarks from the toolbar to make more space for the address bar.

Comment: I've just tried this but it only seems to set the font and size. Long URLs are still truncated.

Comment: Try this (in the userChrome.css file): `To increase the status bar height, enter the following code exactly after the opening lines: <br /><br /> /* change status toolbar height and font */ <br /> #status-bar { <br /> height: (new number) px !important <br / > GO <br /> }

* To make the status bar noticeably larger, you will need to choose a number larger than 25 pixels.`

Comment: Just tried the height:50px trick and it does increase height, but the text doesn't wrap (even with white-space:normal or pre-line). Maybe the text box is resolutely single line and not meant to wrap... :\

Comment: Then I guess that the text box cannot be customized, despite the "customize Firefox pretty much any way you like!" motto...(on second thought they did say "pretty much"). Have you tried looking for other browsers that might allow customizing the address bar text box? Also, how important is it for you to see the *whole* URL?

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution with Firefox. It's not the end of the world, but I know I could be more productive if I didn't have to mouse and keyboard to see the end of the URL. Alt-D and End will have to do. Cheers for trying to figure this one out.

Comment: I've looked for a way to make Firefox show the last part of the URL instead of this first part (i.e show `o.com/userID=1234567` instead of `www.foo.com/userID=123`, as it would've been sufficient, but I couldn't find any way to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This does not expand the address bar vertically, but does align the text so that you can see the end.

I realize this is an old question, but based on the discussion in the comments of the other answer, this may help people.

Add the following to your [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/):

```css
#urlbar-input:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left !important;
    direction: rtl !important;
}

#urlbar-input {
  mask-image: none !important;
}
```

I originally thought to use `text-align: right`, but `text-align: left` has the added benefit of keeping shorter URLs on the left side of the bar as normal.

[image: short URL]

For longer URLs, it aligns the text to start from the right so you can see the end of the URL.

[image: long URL]

Tested using the Wikipedia page for [Lopado­temacho­selacho­galeo­kranio­leipsano­drim­hypo­trimmato­silphio­karabo­melito­katakechy­meno­kichl­epi­kossypho­phatto­perister­alektryon­opte­kephallio­kigklo­peleio­lagoio­siraio­baphe­tragano­pterygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lopado%C2%ADtemacho%C2%ADselacho%C2%ADgaleo%C2%ADkranio%C2%ADleipsano%C2%ADdrim%C2%ADhypo%C2%ADtrimmato%C2%ADsilphio%C2%ADkarabo%C2%ADmelito%C2%ADkatakechy%C2%ADmeno%C2%ADkichl%C2%ADepi%C2%ADkossypho%C2%ADphatto%C2%ADperister%C2%ADalektryon%C2%ADopte%C2%ADkephallio%C2%ADkigklo%C2%ADpeleio%C2%ADlagoio%C2%ADsiraio%C2%ADbaphe%C2%ADtragano%C2%ADpterygon) as a long URL.

The modification to `mask-image: none !important;` is to remove the fade out effect on the right side of the text so it is fully visible.

[image: mask-image fade]